# Pull values from nested arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, loops

I have an array named societies:

```
List<Society> societies = new ArrayList<>();
```

That holds the following data:

```
[{"society_id":1,"name":"TestName1","email":"Test@email1","description":"TestDes‌​1"},
{"society_id":2,"name":"TestName2","email":"Test@email2","description":"TestD‌​es2"},
{"society_id":3,"name":"TestName3","email":"Test@email3","description":"Tes‌​tDes3"}}
```

I will be using this to populate a ListView but am having trouble writing the loop that will assign each array of values to its spot in the ListView. 
I would like to find a way of pulling the values from the Array and assigning them to each list item by using a loop, can anybody help me with this?

My code (should be sufficient but if you need to see more please ask):

```
public class SocietySearch extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_society_search);


        List<Society> societies = new ArrayList<>();
        ServerRequests serverRequest1 = new ServerRequests(SocietySearch.this);
        serverRequest1.GetSocietyDataAsyncTask(societies, new GetSocietyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Society> societies) {
                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
                List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

                items.add(new ListViewItem() {{
                    ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.test;
                    Title = societies.socName;
                    Subtitle = societies.socDes;
                }});

                CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(SocietySearch.this, items);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }


    class ListViewItem {
        public int ThumbnailResource;
        public String Title;
        public String Subtitle;
    }
```

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<SocietySearch.ListViewItem> items;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<SocietySearch.ListViewItem> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_row);

        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Auto-generated method stub

        ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

        View vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

        ImageView test = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

        test.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
        txtTitle.setText(item.Title);
        txtSubTitle.setText(item.Subtitle);


        return vi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we came to the conclusion, that we need to have the for loop to iterate through all the Society classes in the SocietySearch class:

```
@Override
public void done(List<Society> societies) {
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Society s : societies) {
        items.add(new ListViewItem() {{
            ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.test;
            Title = s.socName;
            Subtitle = s.socDes;
        }});
    }
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(
        SocietySearch.this, items);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}`
```

And we also had to fix the ArrayAdapter implementation:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<SocietySearch.ListViewItem> items;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<SocietySearch.ListViewItem> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_row, **items**); // the constructor 
        //needs the reference of the list, even though we use our variable to 
        //populate the rows. I guess it has to know how many elements it contains to
        //iterate then through getView method, which is called for each row

        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a custom solution? So that you would bind each ListViewItem state to the corresponding column, then you have to create the custom solution like it is [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter). You would need to have a custom layout for each line and extend the ArrayAdapter where you bind each column for a line.

Is this what you want to know? If not, can you be more specific please.

Comment: I have the adapter already, I would like to find a way of pulling the values from the Array and assigning them to each list item by using a loop. I have added the custom adapter for you to see.

Comment: It does? Then maybe I should ask how to assign the values in my onCreate.. Specifically `Title = societies.socName;` Not too sure on that one.

Comment: You want this
`for(Society s : societies) {items.add(new ListViewItem() {{
                    ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.test;
                    Title = societies.socName;
                    Subtitle = societies.socDes;
                }});
}`

Comment: You have a list **societies** (`@Override
            public void done(List<Society> societies)`), but you only assign to it one value in the asynchronized task. And then the list contains only one value. And when you bind the item for each line(`@Override
    public View getView(..){}`), the list only contains 1 item, which equals to one row.

Comment: Thats perfect, but I get: Cannot receive symbol 'socDes'

Comment: Yeah, because you call the `Subtitle = societies.socDes;`. Just exchange the **societies.socDes** to **s.socDes**. You can not call this, because your instance is `List<Society> societies`. List does not have this state. You should even get an error here `Title = societies.socName;`. You can not call Society states in the List class, you have to get the instance out of the list. Like I wrote to you the for loop: `for(Society s : societies) {items.add(new ListViewItem() {{ ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.test; Title = s.socName; Subtitle = s.socDes; }}); }`.

Comment: And BTW it is a good approach to hide the states of classes by using private variables and public methods - [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: So are you saying that I should make multiple calls to my AsyncTask for each individual array, rather than a single call that returns my nested array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105831/discussion-between-kmil-and-jernej-k).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an anonymous class and trying to assign values in it's object initializer. Object initializer doesn't have a reference to `societies`, that's why you are getting the compilation error. Try this instead:

```
class ListViewItem {
    private final int ThumbnailResource;
    private final String Title;
    private final String Subtitle;

    public ListViewItem(int thumbnail, String title, String subtitle) {
        ThumbnailResource = thumbnail;
        Title = title;
        Subtitle = subtitle;
    }
}
```

When adding list items:

```
items.add(new ListViewItem(R.drawable.test, societies.socName, societies.socDes);
```